# How to change the size of a picture background

Tags: css

I want to have an image as my background for my site, but I can't change the size of the image. is there any way I can change the size of the picture to fit my site?

P.S.
this is the code i use to display my picture

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/lvl1.jpg');

}
```

Comment: try, giving `background-size:cover` property to your `body` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

or

```
background-size: contain;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property to specify the size of your background image.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11740298)

Comment: @Magicprog.fr Thanks. I will consider this.

Answer (score 0):

use background-size property:

```
body{
    background: url("images/lvl1.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help to fill with the background.

```
body {
  background-image: url('images/lvl1.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-size: cover;`

> The background-size CSS property specifies the size of the background images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or only partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.

[Here is the link for reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/bicycle-1280x720.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```